# How to declare a guid in Knockout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

can someone please point me in the direction as to how to declare GUID in knockout .

for a string and int its

```
self.Idnumber(0);
self.name("");
```

for a guid would it be something like

```
self.Guid(FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC)
```

or just

```
self.Guid(0)
```

Comment: do you need to get a `Guid` generated in the front end? if you just need a knockout variable to hold a guid, just declare it and use it as `self.Id = ko.observable('FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC')`

Comment: now i got it Guid is just a string declare how you declare strings `self.Guid('FAE04EC0-30....')` . cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is no inbuilt `guid` methods in `Knockout` / client side js. To achieve that you can add helper function.

*The below functions returns the perfect `GUID`:*

```
    function guid() {
        return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
            var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
            return v.toString(16);
        });
    }
```

Just add the above code in `your js` which is used globally. And just call this function. It will returns the proper `guid`.

you could declare hard coded guid to observable like below:

```
self.Guid = ko.observable('FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC')
```

To make it dynamic include `guid()` function and do call like below:

```
self.Guid = ko.observable(guid())
```

Assigning after declaration of observable variable:

```
self.Guid(guid());
//or
self.Guid('FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC');
```

Comment: OP is looking for `how to declare` rather how to generate .

Answer (score 2):

I had created like this

```
     function CreateGuid() {
            var guid = (function () {
                function s4() {
                    return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                               .toString(16)
                               .substring(1);
                }
                return function () {
                    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
                           s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
                };
            })();
            return guid();
        }
```

Please check if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

just write javascript guid generator function like

```
var guidGenerator =  function () {
    return {
        newuuid: function () {

            var s = [];
            var hexDigits = "0123456789abcdef";
            for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
                s[i] = hexDigits.substr(Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x10), 1);
            }
            s[14] = "4";  // bits 12-15 of the time_hi_and_version field to 0010
            s[19] = hexDigits.substr((s[19] & 0x3) | 0x8, 1);  // bits 6-7 of the clock_seq_hi_and_reserved to 01
            s[8] = s[13] = s[18] = s[23] = "-";
            return s.join("");
        }
    }
```

call it like

```
self.guid(guidGenerator.newuudid());
```

hope it help's you

Comment: was just looking for a declaration method

Comment: This is a simpler way I came across   `function createGUID() {
    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
          .toString(16)
          .substring(1);
    }
    return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
      s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
}`

Answer (score 0):

KO doesn't have a default type guid, but below a suggestion.

Client Side JS:

```
//This is a function to help verify that the guid is empty, good for future usage.
    function IsGuidEmpty (guid) {
        var emptyGuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
        if (guid === emptyGuid)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    //This is a function to set the guid to empty.
 function () SetEmptyGuid {
        var emptyGuid = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
        return emptyGuid;
    }
```

KO ViewModel:

```
self.Guid = ko.observable(SetEmptyGuid());
```

Server Side C#:

```
// your API or controller
     if (yourGuid != Guid.Empty)
    {
        //Todo
    }
```